# Uma transição ou efeito

Tags: javascript, html, css

Alguém teria alguma ideia de alguma transição ou efeito de alguma imagem surgir da esquerda pra direita em um sentido de estar passando em uma linha reta?

Comment: Tem algum exemplo para visualizar o que você está querendo?

Comment: Pior que não tenho, mas é como se passasse em uma linha reta e saisse da esquerda para a direita.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma alternativa em JS puro. Usei `setInterval` (temporizador contínuo) que é cancelado com `clearInterval` quando a imagem desaparecer da tela. Para saber quando a imagem desaparece da tela eu usei `offsetLeft` que me dá a posição da imagem à partir da esquerda da tela. Quando a posição for maior que a área da janela (`window.innerWidth`) eu paro o temporizador `setInterval`.

No CSS eu setei `position: fixed` para não causar scroll horizontal na janela, e coloquei também `left: -200px` para que a imagem fique fora da janela à esquerda, onde `200px` é a largura da imagem. `top: 20px;` é a distância da imagem ao topo da janela.

Em `img.offsetLeft+10` o valor `10` representa quantos pixels a imagem vai correr. O `30` no temporizador é o tempo em milissegundos entre os ciclos do temporizador. Quando maior esse valor, mais lentamente irá ocorrer o ciclo, ou seja, mais lentamente a imagem irá se mover.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   var img = document.querySelector("#imagem");
   var tempo = setInterval(function(){
      img.offsetLeft > window.innerWidth ?
      clearInterval(tempo)
      : img.style.left = img.offsetLeft+10+"px";
   }, 30);
});
```

```css
#imagem{
   position: fixed;
   top: 20px;
   left: -200px;
}
```

```html
<img id="imagem" width="200" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" />
```

#### Repetição após 10 segundos

Criando um gatilho que simula o evento `DOMContentLoaded`:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   var img = document.querySelector("#imagem");
   var tempo = setInterval(function(){
      if(img.offsetLeft > window.innerWidth){
         clearInterval(tempo);
         setTimeout(function(){
            img.style.left = "-200px";
            var evt = document.createEvent('Event');  
            evt.initEvent('DOMContentLoaded', false, false);  
            document.dispatchEvent(evt);
         }, 10000);
      }else{
         img.style.left = img.offsetLeft+10+"px";
      }
   }, 30);
});
```

```css
#imagem{
   position: fixed;
   top: 20px;
   left: -200px;
}
```

```html
<img id="imagem" width="200" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" />
```

Comment: Valeu! você saberia me dizer se tem como passar de 10 em 10 segundos?

Comment: @JeanAlves Adicionei na resposta. Abs!